# Groovy script error on jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins

hi i am new to groovy.

I am using jenkins to do my build, now my requirement is to capture the build result e.g (Success/Unstable.Failure) and print it on the subject line of my build email.

I have installed groovy postbuild plugin and trying to execute the following lines but with no success:

import hudson.model.*

status = manager.build.result
println ${status}

and then i would include the status variable on the subject line of my email-ext plugin.

But i am getting the following error:

```
Groovy script failed:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.$() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@2620749c]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:4)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder.perform(GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java:276)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:710)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:685)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:162)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:632)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1463)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
```

please could someone help me

Comment: Is there a new line after "status = manager.build.result", isn't it? Can you please wrap your code as you did for the error?

Answer (score 0):

`${BUILD_STATUS}` is already available without resorting to groovy, and can be used in your email template just by using `${BUILD_STATUS}`

Comment: Hi i think i was not clear....   I need to display the build status of a upstream build in the subject line of my email. There if i put ${BUILD_STATUS} it takes the status of the current build but that is not what i want. I want it to display the upstream status.

Comment: hi i have found the following code over the internet, but not sure if this will solve my issue:upstreamBuilds = manager.build.getUpstreamBuilds();
upstreamJob = upstreamBuilds.keySet().iterator().next();
lastUpstreamBuild = upstreamJob.getLastBuild();
if(lastUpstreamBuild.getResult().isBetterThan(manager.build.result)) {
    lastUpstreamBuild.setResult(manager.build.result);
}